# returning response from firebase push

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

i have a code to create a new record in firebase realtime DB as below

```
assignCoupon(email:string, discType: string, discVal: number, code:string){

    let coupon = {
      "discType" : discType,
      "discVal": discVal,
      "code": code
    }

    this.db.list('/users/' + uid + '/coupons').push(coupon).then(
      (resp) => console.log("user created with:" + resp)
    )

  }
```

This works fine. But i need to return the response as a promise back to the calling code so that i can show a message to user. unlike  snapshotChanges() this does not return a subscribe. So how do i do it in this case? To be clear trying to use the same style as in my below code

```
getOrderHistory(uid:string){
    console.log('start of getOrderHistory with uid:' + uid)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      {
        this.db.object("/users/" + uid + "/orders").snapshotChanges().map(
          (snapshot) => {return snapshot.payload.val()}
        ).subscribe(
          res => {
            //console.log('response:' + res)
            resolve(res)
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
          }
        )
      })
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand.  `push()` returns a promise-like object.  You're even calling `then()` on it right there in your code.  Is there something wrong with that promise?

Comment: well the problem is that i am not able to return it back to the calling function which is on my UI side to show alert etc. Like the 2nd example i gave where i am returning the data back to the calling method.

Comment: You can't just `return this.db.list(...).push(...)`?  That should return the promise from your function.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is outside the scope of your question, your question has been answered in the comments.

Looking at your `getOrderHistory` function, you can clean up the promise a bit by using `rxjs/toPromise`.

If you use `valueChanges()` instead of `snapshotChanges()` you won't need to `map` the response, as `angularfire2` returns the payload value.

Using the `.pipe(first())` method will take the first subscription event (or null if the data doesn't exist) and wrap it as a promise.

This optimised function should do the same thing as your example above and won't leave you with subscriptions that you need to unsubscribe from as the `first` operator will close the subscription after it's received the first value.

```
// Import the operator
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';


getOrderHistory(uid: string) {
    return this.db.object(`/users/${uid}/orders`)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(first())
      .toPromise();
  }
```